# language and database suitable for data driven game like football manager

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a Cricket management game (like Football Manager) written in VB 6.0 long back. It uses MS-Access as it's back-end and win-32 API calls to draw UI screens. It's a reasonably big game with 90,000+ lines of code.

Now, I want to re-write the game using other technologies like Java, Python, C++ etc. Basically I want to get out of Microsoft technologies (and preferably move to technologies that are available for free).

So, please help me out in choosing right technologies for Application-Logic, UI and Database. Below are my broader requirements regarding the three layers.

**Application-Logic:**
The game needs to make 1000s of calculations on in-memory data and constantly write that data to text files (Save game files). It also needs to do very fast database operations.

**UI:**
The UI need not be very robust. The only requirement is to be able to develop good looking screens with minimal animation effects. Below are the links to current screen images for your reference.
http://imageshack.us/g/148/89832593.png/
I might also add 2D graphics in the future.

**Database:**
The database contains around 20 tables with the larger tables containing up to 300000 records. Again, I want to use a free database like MySQL or flat text files. I am very curious to know about the database used by games like "Football Manager" or "Cricket Coach 2011"

**Note: Please don't consider the efforts required to learn the proposed technologies. I will take care of them.**

**Update:**
 
Now that I have decided to go ahead with C++ and SQLite, please direct me regarding the IDE and basic Tools/Libraries I should be using to start with.

I am already experienced in working with "Visual Studio" and "Eclipse". Can I use one of them? or can I go with QT (I read that QT is cross platform, but, is it just for mobile development or can I use it for desktop apps too)?

And, 
How critical is the IDE selection initially? 
Can I move to a different IDE at a later stage?
If I use Visual Studio, am I getting bound to Microsoft technologies?

If possible, please give me links to any examples to develop screens as in the links I provided above.

Answer (score 2):

[I see now that an "online game" was an assumption on my part.  So keep that in mind as you read this.]

I would take into consideration your hosting options.  If you want to open-source this or operate it on a shoe-string budget, and run it on the widest array of available hosting services, then you probably want to go with LAMP technologies.  This would rule out my favorite language, Java, as the underlying choice of language.  PHP is almost always available on inexpensive hosting options.  Perl and then Python are also available on many hosts, but PHP is practically guaranteed these days.

If however, you'll be hosting this in a "whatever it takes" environment, I'm a big fan of Java, Tomcat, JBoss, etc.  But those technologies, while powerful, take a lot of time to ramp up to use, but more importantly, to use effectively and efficiently.

MySQL is a great choice these days for databases.  Postgresql is another free option (in some ways, maybe free-er than MySQL, given MySQL's Oracle connection.)  But MySQL is likely to be more readily available on a lot of inexpensive hosts.  MySQL also qualifies under "very fast operation."

Regardless of database choice, do what you can to abstract your database code so that should you want to change (or need to change) you can do it with minimal fuss.  PHP and Java both have well worn ORMs to help you in this regard.

It'd be interesting to see what kind of data models are used in a game like a * Manager title.  I suspect it maps well to a relational database.  But I'm personally on the lookout for a good reason to dabble with a NoSQL solution.

HTML and CSS for the client to start.

Comment: Hello Marvo, a NoSQL solution is on my mind for backend. But I am not sure about how to implement it. Further guidance would be appreciated. By the way, My application is a desktop application. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I think your question was perfectly clear.  I was simply projecting my own ideas onto yours.  =)

I've attended a few talks about NoSQL solutions at user groups, but that's it.  I haven't heard of any that are desktop solutions, though.

Comment: I will also mention that Java is a viable language for a game like this that runs on the desktop.  It gives you portability, looks the same on each platform if you use Swing or something comparable, and for the type of game in question, would provide the necessary performance (assuming no twitch elements anywhere in the game.)  It would require the installation of a JVM, however, but a .NET solution would require a VM too.  (Yet another plug for my language of choice.)

Comment: And BerkeleyDB would work for an embedded key-value store.  (There must be a comparable database solution that doesn't come with Oracle attached.)

Answer (score 1):

For a database, I would recommend SQLite: http://sqlite.org/

It's free, fast, and serverless. Serverless being key. There are some drawbacks that you can read about on their website, but for a stand-alone application, it should be much better than using text files.

Comment: Hello John, Does it have drivers for languages like Java and Python?

Comment: @Srikanth: Here is a list of wrappers: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers  It appears to have everything under the sun.